# How can I improve my Adobe Air iOS App start time?

Tags: ios, air, startup

I built an Air application that runs on Android devices and iOS devices. The application uses Air 3.4 and Flex SDK 4.6. On my Android device, the application starts in 5 seconds. On my iPad device, the application starts in 95 seconds.

My application has a splash screen, which is launched via the ViewNavigatorApplication property, splashScreenImage. Here is what I see on each device.

### iPad 2 - ipa size, 11.7M

12 seconds of black screen. Then my splash screen appears.
90+ seconds of splash screen. Then my first view appears.

### Android Nexus 7 - apk size, 4.0M

2.5 seconds of black screen. Then my splash screen appears.
2.5 seconds of splash screen. Then my first view appears.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without details of your app, it's virtually impossible to yield anything constructive or concise.  Per Android, I'm assuming you have not prepackaged Adobe AIR Captive Runtime given the footprint size.

Comment: Here are more details about my app. It's a video conferencing app. So I have to set renderMode to "cpu". The app has 5 views and several popups. The popups use the SkinnablePopupContainer. The app uses dependency injection as provided by the Parsley framework to share two small data objects between the views. The app uses web service calls to manage the conference state. The app has about 400k of images which are rendered using the MultiDPIBitmapSource. The app has 43.3K of icons for the various sizes as specified in the application xml file.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to move graphical assets and sounds to different SWF files, and load them during run time.

Obviously, the loading time in iOS depends heavily on the size of the binary file. Moving stuff to external files means those won't need to load when the app starts. If you follow this path, be aware that loading data from the SWF could slow the performance of your app. For example if your app is a game, don't do it in the middle of a level...

Check this article from Adobe:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/combine-swfs-with-swcs.html

> Remember, it is possible to load SWF files on iOS, but the code inside them won't be interpreted. Loading a SWF in this way is useful for graphical assets such as animations or vector graphics. You can create a library full of symbols and simply pick the symbol that you want to use.

That means that your SWF can't contain any AS code.

Comment: SWC are compile time, and cannot be loaded dynamically.  SWZ RSL would be an option for Android; however, with AIR for iOS there is no such option.

Comment: You are right, I've edited my answer accordingly. At least for iOS...